# Are there any add-ons for Visual Studio to help manage todo comments?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

Our solution has a lot of todo comments, but unfortunately it seems the only way to sort them is by file. Sorting by project would give me a much better overview of what I'm actually responsible for. Just wondering if there's any way to do this or any add-ins that provide better functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Resharper 4.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) does this for you.  They have a "To-do Explorer".  Uses comments to find TODO, Note and Bug comments.

**Edit:**
Here is a link to the [actual feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#To-do_Explorer).

Comment: Arg if it were $2 and sold stand-alone I'd be set. $200?  Nah.

Comment: The tool is WELL worth the price.  It is a great add-on for VS.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using trusty find-in-files for **`todo:`** which can be limited to the current project or a user defined folder set.  Your wallet may vary.